# What is the Molien series of the SO(2)-invariant ring on the plane (sometimes written C[X]^{SO(2)} )?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory, classical-invariant-theory

Let SO(2) be the group of rotations in the plane. What is the Molien series (sometimes called the Hilbert-Poincare series) of the SO(2)-invariant ring of polynomials?

N.B. The main goal being to calculate the generating set of the SO(2)-invariant ring of polynomials on the plane.

Comment: Toward the main goal of identifying generators for the invariant ring, a direct route is Weyl's "First Fundamental Theorem" on the invariants of $SO(d)$ acting on an $m$-tuple of vectors, which says that the invariant ring is generated by the pairwise dot products of the vectors and the $d\times d$ minors of the matrix made from them. Your case is $d=2$, $m=1$ so the matrix is $2\times 1$, so there are no $2x2$ minors, and the ring is generated by the dot product of the single vector by itself, which is $x^2+y^2$ as in Qiaochu's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Write $z = x + iy, \bar{z} = x - iy$ as usual, where $x, y \in \mathbb{C}[x, y]$ are regarded as complex-valued polynomial functions on the plane. The action of $SO(2)$ diagonalizes as

$$z \mapsto e^{i \theta} z, \bar{z} \mapsto e^{-i \theta} \bar{z}$$

so a monomial $z^n \bar{z}^m$ is sent to $e^{i(n-m)\theta} z^n \bar{z}^m$. So the invariant polynomials are given by $z^n \bar{z}^n = (x^2 + y^2)^n$; they are generated by $x^2 + y^2$ and the Molien series is $\frac{1}{1 - t^2}$.

Alternatively we can compute the Molien series as an integral

$$\int_{S^1} \frac{1}{\det(1 - tr_{\theta})} \, d \theta$$

where $r_{\theta} = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ - \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{array} \right]$ is the rotation by $\theta$. The denominator of the integrand is $(1 - t \cos \theta)^2 + t^2 \sin^2 \theta = t^2 - 2t \cos \theta + 1$, which gives

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{t^2 + 1 - 2t \cos \theta} \, d \theta.$$

WolframAlpha suggests this integral can be evaluated by a tangent half-angle substitution but at this point it seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I want to generate group-theory lemmas based on reals $\forall_{b\,}\!\exists_{a\, b\, c\,}a^{2}+ b^{2}+ c^{2}- ab- bc\geq 2\left | ca \right |\!$, which is validated by $a, b, c:=\!a- b, b- b, c- b$. I even was stuck on writing a property for that. I need to your help. Thanks a real lot !

Comment: My inspiration_ https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82634624.pdf, yeah, I am stupid.